# Is it possible to run an Android Tablet emulator with API <= 15?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

From what I understand:

- host GPU emulation is not supported for API <= 15
- GPU emulation is required for displays >= 768x1280

Is that correct?

And is it just impossible to run an AVD for a pre-API-15 tablet or is there any workaround?

Comment: I am able to see APIs since 2.1 into Android studio, while creating tablet emulator.

Comment: The point of an emulator is to emulate *existing* devices. Stop wasting time.

Comment: @PankajKumar Did you succeeed to boot it?

Comment: @EugenPechanec Such devices actually exist

Comment: @fiddler I know they do exist, I'm just advising you to focus on the remaining 99.9% of devices in use. Everyone would much rather see you implement e.g. runtime permissions.

Answer (score 0):

once i read this on intel website that you could use gpu in api 15. but you have to use 15 api revision .
see this details.

(copied from intel website.)

[image]